# Nginx proxy with Redmine SVN authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, svn, reverse-proxy, redmine

I am attempting to setup a system where I have an nginx server running as a reverse proxy for multiple websites that I want to run. To separate the websites I have created a Linux container which contains each site to allow me to reduce conflicts in database usage etc.

I am currently trying to get my main site working and have nginx with passenger setup and connecting to redmine and I have an Apache install specifically setup for serving the SVN over HTTP and am attempting to use the redmine authentication with that.

I have set everything up as described in the redmine howtos, but when I check a project out from the SVN it always works even if the project is private and whenever I try and commit to the repositories it fails saying "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem", the Apache error log related to that event is "(20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/srv/rcs/svn/error/format': No such file or directory". If I take out the redmine authentication I can checkout and check-in repositories fine but there is no authentication.

Does anyone have any ideas?

*Edit*

I tried to solve this problem another way by attempting to have the authentication work by LDAP, I managed to get it so that my user could log into the redmine website but as soon as I tried to check anything out it said that access was forbidden to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be an apache configuration issue due to a default value set into apache's configuration. The following link provided the information to solve the problem:

http://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/896.html